# How can scientists deduce the number of types of neutrinos, or 'effective number', from Planck satellite data?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang-theory, cosmic-microwave-background, neutrinos, theories

Is it related to the way they deduce the Hubble constant from Planck data?

Would more types of oscillating and mixing neutrinos mean faster or slower expansion of the universe?

Would a fourth mass eigenstate necessarily be heavier than the three we already know about?  Would it have caused earlier 'decoupling' from everything else?

Comment: Not 100% sure here so I’m not gonna post this as an answer, but I believe I’ve heard that sometimes neutrino rates can be approximated by otherwise unexplained energy/ momentum loss that comes from neutrino producing events. Also you have quite a few questions here, maybe try narrowing it down a bit and making multiple posts.